# Change default RESTFul actions laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I created a controller named `CatController` with `php artisan make:controller CatController`. <strike>So it generated the next route list:</strike>*-> What generated the route list is on routes.php `Route::resource('cat','CatsController');`

```
| Domain | Method   | URI               | Name        | Action                                          | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                 |             | Furbook\Http\Controllers\CatController@index   |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | cat               | cat.index   | Furbook\Http\Controllers\CatController@index   |            |
|        | POST     | cat               | cat.store   | Furbook\Http\Controllers\CatController@store   |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | cat/create        | cat.create  | Furbook\Http\Controllers\CatController@create  |            |
|        | DELETE   | cat/{cat}         | cat.destroy | Furbook\Http\Controllers\CatController@destroy |            |
|        | PATCH    | cat/{cat}         |             | Furbook\Http\Controllers\CatController@update  |            |
|        | PUT      | cat/{cat}         | cat.update  | Furbook\Http\Controllers\CatController@update  |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | cat/{cat}         | cat.show    | Furbook\Http\Controllers\CatController@show    |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | cat/{cat}/edit    | cat.edit    | Furbook\Http\Controllers\CatController@edit    |            |
```

Later on I thought it would be better to call it CatsController and handle the urls as `cats/...` so I renamed the controller but I still have the same default REST actions URIs.

Is there anyway to change it? How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge the `make:controller` command only generates the controller file, not any route definitions. The routes defined there look like they've beed generated by a `Route::resource` definition that would look like this:

```
Route::resource('cat', 'CatController');
```

To make that work with `cats` and `CatsControllers` you should change it to this:

```
Route::resource('cats', 'CatsController');
```

You can read more on [RESTful Resource Controllers in the Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

Comment: that's it! i Ichanged it wrongly to : `Route::resource('cat', 'CatsController');`Thanks